# Azure Sql DB Restore not showing up in Azure portal but stuck restoring in SSMS

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, database-restore, azure-deployment, point-in-time-recovery

I have had an Azure SQL DB point in time restore running for two days. I want to cancel it as I think there is an issue. I can see the DB restoring in SSMS but can't find the deployment in my Azure Portal. Does anyone know how to cancel it? I have tried using Azure CLI but I can't see the resource.

[image]

Comment: Can you share more on the reason you are restoring (Data recovery or Database replacement or Deleted database restore) ? if you delete the database during the restore, the restore operation will be canceled. You can refer to Powershell module for point-in-time restore. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.sql/restore-azsqldatabase

Comment: So I was doing a point in time restore, on a S0 tier Azure Sql db with a size of 2Gb. The process ran for 2 days without completing. I can no longer see the deployment in Azure Portal but the db is showing up in SSMS on the Server Instance. I tried to drop the database but this did not resolve the issue. I will add some screen grabs.

Comment: @JoshuaAlexanderStewart, this issue is actually very important and you should report it to Microsoft. If you need to deploy a backup ASAP restoring is the only option. We are talking about a "service down" of about 8h here. Think if this happens on your production environment.

Comment: @FrancescoMantovani yes this was far too long. My advice to anyone doing a restore on the S0 Standard DB tier is to restore to a DB on the S2 tier and then downgrade the service once the restore is complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called `Azure Hiccups`, it happened to me yesterday on Switzerland West region between 10:20 and 10:40.

I re-run it and everything was fixed.

If I check the [Activity Log](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_ActivityLog/ActivityLogBlade) I can see the error:

[image]

But if I browse in the [Service Health](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Health/AzureHealthBrowseBlade/healthHistory/navigateTo/healthHistory) it says everything was good:

[image]

> What to do in case of `Azure Hiccups`:

1. **FIX:** Re-run the task, hopefully it will fix the issue, like when you hit an old TV with your fist.
2. **PREVENT:** You can *try* to create an Activity Log alert but once again it will be based on Service Health (which says that everything is good) and not on the actual Activity Log. So you will probably miss issues like this and will discover the problem 24h later.
3. **POST-MORTEM:** You can take a screenshot of the failed task/service in the Activity Log, show it to Microsoft and ask for a refund if possible. For the future you can check the current status of Azure in the official [Status page](https://status.azure.com/en-us/status) and subscribe to the RSS feed. You can browse the [Azure Status History](https://status.azure.com/en-us/status/history/). But as I said none of the last two reports the `Azure Hiccups` so the screenshot of the Activity Log is still the only proof that a tree yesterday has fallen in the forest.

As Microsoft [SLA says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/high-availability-sla) that the High availability for Azure SQL Database and SQL Managed Instance is 99.99% of the year you can start collecting those screenshot and open tickets with their support.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After dropping the Database this morning, the operation status of which was unsuccessful. The Restore has finally been canceled 8 hrs after attempting to drop the database.

Comment: Have you experienced something similar?

Comment: Is you that stopped the restore procedure?

Comment: I never stopped the deployment in Azure but it disappeared from the portal leaving the DB in a restoring state but a 2GB restore shouldn't run for 2 days. Eventually, I tried to drop the database. The SQL log said this failed but then 4 hours later the DB dissapeared from my SSMS Object explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution, just create a new database of the same name. And the restoring one will be replaced with the one created, then you can delete it.